# RecyclerView won't show items until switched between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am designing an app that has 4 different fragments on the homeActivity using bottomNavigation to switch between them and on the first page that I am using as a news feed, the items do not show until I switch to a different fragment, then back again. I understand there are problems similar to this on SO but no solutions seem to help in my case.
I assume the problem is something to do with the difference in onCreate() and onCreateView in fragments.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

View v;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Drink> drinksList;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drinksList = new ArrayList<>();
    drinksList.add(new Drink("Latte",999,"Coffee","test",1.99,77,R.drawable.latte));
    drinksList.add(new Drink("Black Tea",123,"Tea", "test", 1.50,11,R.drawable.blacktea));

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(drinksList,getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

**EDIT** 
adding HomeActivity

public void setUpMenuNav() {

```
    mMainFrame = findViewById(R.id.mainFrame);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNaviationView);

    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    socialFragment = new SocialFragment();
    trackingFragment = new TrackingFragment();
    locationFragment = new LocationFragment();

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navHome:
                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navSocial:
                    setFragment(socialFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navTracking:
                    setFragment(trackingFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navLocation:
                    setFragment(locationFragment);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });

}


    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Then setUpMenuBar is called in the onCreate() method

Comment: Didn't you forget to add fragment inside activitie's onCreate?

Comment: On my HomeActivity I have a method that setFragment(Fragment) that sets the fragment depending on which tab the user selects. If that's what you mean? all the other fragments work just seems to be some sort of initialisation problem

Comment: Why don't you do all in onCreateView() method?

Comment: That's what I initially had and I changed it to the current setup to see if it would work, but unfortunately hasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your `onCreate()` method on `HomeActivity` add `setFragment(new HomeFragment())`.
that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks but I already have this in homeActivity. The problem isn't displaying the fragment, it's showing the items when the app is launched. They eventually appear after moving around between fragments

Comment: sure, ive added it in

Comment: after the line homeFragment = new HomeFragment(); add setFragment(homeFragment)

Comment: I have that in the case statement?

Comment: the case statement occurs only when you actually press the bottom navigation item.
if you want to add the fragment on the creation of the activity the method must be called within the onCreate() method, and not on the anonymous callback which will be called only when you actually press the item.

Comment: anyway, when you add the setFragment() call don't forget to verify that the activity is not restoring it's state (aka if(savedInstanceState == null) setFragment(homeFragment)) that will save you some bugs later on :)